# knockout if with function inside a template

Tags: knockout.js

Continuing my study journey with knockout I encountered the following problem.

I try to output few galleries together with pictures inside of them. Nothing special and my model looks like this:

```
this.elements = ko.observableArray([{
    type: 'img',
    text: 'fish',
    imgs: ko.observableArray([
        'http://c1.wag.com/images/products/rdg/rdg-010_Small2a.jpg',
        'https://www.uoguelph.ca/cio/sites/uoguelph.ca.cio/files/images/SmallFish_0.jpg'
    ])
}, ...]);
```

But I want to have the following functionality. When there are not images in imgs, write about it.

So I tried it with `<div data-bind="if: !imgs.length">No images</div>` inside my template. But with no result (check [my fiddle for the whole code](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/zeqg9/1/)). The output is written in every iteration.

But when I try to do the similar thing but explicitly showing the number of images, [it works nicely](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/zeqg9/2/).

So what is the problem with my `imgs.length` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `!imgs().length` (with `()`).
`imgs` is observable array, so it is function and you should execute it before get `length` property of array.

Comment: Thanks. This is the second time I was bitten by this (). Have to remember: Observers are functions.... I will accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `imgs().length`. The imgs is observable array and its length can be accesses with use of `()`. See Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zeqg9/5/)